# The name 'result' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Now when I run the program it's giving me the `operator` error message even when I input a correct `operator`. Any ideas?
Also thank you guys for the result fix. It was greatly appreciated :) I'm thinking that I somehow misused the code for the `IsValidData()` method definition and called it wrong in the `IsOperator(txtOperator, "+,-,*,/")` area.

```
   ` private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //Set Validation
            if(IsValidData())
            {

                decimal Operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal (txtOperand1.Text);
                string Operator = Convert.ToString (txtOperator.Text);
                decimal Operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand2.Text);
                decimal result = Calculate(Operand1, Operator, Operand2);

                txtResult.Text = result.ToString("f4");
                txtOperand1.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" +       ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
        }
    }
    //Set IsValidData()
    public bool IsValidData()
    {
        return
            IsPresent(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
            IsDecimal(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
            IsWithinRange(txtOperand1, "Operand 1", 0, 1000000) &&

            IsPresent(txtOperator, "Operator") &&
            IsOperator(txtOperator, "+,-,*,/") &&

            IsPresent(txtOperand2, "Operand 2") &&
            IsDecimal(txtOperand2, "Operand 2") &&
            IsWithinRange(txtOperand2, "Operand 2", 0, 1000000);
    }
    //Setup IsPresent
    public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is required to continue.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
    //Setup IsDecimal
    public bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal value.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Setup IsOperator
    public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string operators)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string s in operators.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
            {
                if (textBox.Text.Trim() == s)
                    return true;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException("The operator must be a valid operator: +,-, *, /", "name");
            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            txtOperator.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Setup IsWithinRange.
    public bool IsWithinRange(TextBox textBox, string name, decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
        if (number < min || number > max)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //Setup Calculate Method.
    private decimal Calculate(decimal Operand1, string Operator, decimal Operand2)
    {
        if (Operator == "+")
        {
            decimal result = Operand1 + Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "-")
        {
            decimal result = Operand1 - Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "*")
        {
            decimal result = Operand1 * Operand2;
        }
        else
        {
            decimal result = Operand1 / Operand2;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your variable outside of the if/else statement scopes. When defining a variable inside of the If/Else statement, that variable loses scope once the function exits that if/else statement.

```
decimal result;
if (Operator == "+")
        {
            result = Operand1 + Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "-")
        {
            result = Operand1 - Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "*")
        {
            result = Operand1 * Operand2;
        }
        else
        {
            result = Operand1 / Operand2;
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: @user3413431 - no problem, glad to help.  Be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted (by clicking the green checkmark) once you are able to do so.  This lets others that might have the same problem to know what the final solution was!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to help with the edited problem?

Comment: @user3413431 - I agree with Grant, you don't want to change the context of your original question as it makes the answers seem to not make much sense / people may not know what you were asking to start with.  There is no penalty for multiple questions on SO and its actually encouraged to ask specific, single problem questions :)

Answer (score 2):

In the `Calculate` method, you've created a new variable called `result` four times, in each part of the `if` statement, but it doesn't technically exist (it's out of scope) when you try to return it.

Define it once, before the `if` statement, then set the value.

```
private decimal Calculate(decimal Operand1, string Operator, decimal Operand2)
{
    decimal result;

    if (Operator == "+")
    {
        result = Operand1 + Operand2;
    }
    else if (Operator == "-")
    {
        result = Operand1 - Operand2;
    }
    else if (Operator == "*")
    {
        result = Operand1 * Operand2;
    }
    else
    {
        result = Operand1 / Operand2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable named result in the scope.

```
  //Setup Calculate Method.
    private decimal Calculate(decimal Operand1, string Operator, decimal Operand2)
    {
        decimal result;
        if (Operator == "+")
        {
            result = Operand1 + Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "-")
        {
            result = Operand1 - Operand2;
        }
        else if (Operator == "*")
        {
            result = Operand1 * Operand2;
        }
        else
        {
            result = Operand1 / Operand2;
        }
        return result;
    }
```